# UISegmented Control Global Tint in Navigation Controller Header

Tags: ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

Setting the global tint in my tableview header isn't tinting as expected, and appears to be a bug.

When I load the view I get

[image]

The right hand side retains the default colour, however if I press the right button and the left again it sets to how you would expect it to be:

[image]

This problem is only with the segmented control in my navigation bar. The global tinting works when the control is embedded in a "normal" view.

I have a work around which solves the problem. Being, I setting the right control and then back to the left in viewDidLoad.

So is it a bug ? or am i missing something? Thanks.

Add: I am setting the global tint in the storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. Global tinting works for the objects, whose class is used for tinting. If the specific tint scheme is declared for a class, then all the controls belonging to that class will follow the class tint scheme regardless of the view they are added to.

I have tried implementing this & I am here with this code.

Set the global Tinting for `UINavigationBar` in `appDelegate`

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
   ...
   ...
}
```

and I am adding `UISegmentControl` in `UINavigationBar` as well as in`tableView.tableHeaderView` in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:@[@"One", @"Two"]];
segment.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-75, 0, 150, 40);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:segment];

UISegmentedControl *tableSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:@[@"One", @"Two"]];
tableSegment.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-75, 0, 150, 40);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:tableSegment];
tableView.tableHeaderView = tableSegment;
```

This yields following result. The `UISegmentControl` will be tinted with the `UINavigationBar` 's global tint if it is added into the `UINavigationBar` container as SubView, otherwise, it will take the default blue color outside `UINavigationBar` like in the header of `UITableView`

[image: UINavigationBar Tint]

Now adding a specific tint color for `UISegmentedControl` as

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
   ...
   ...
}
```

``

It yields this, The `UISegmentControl` is affected by its global tint now, regardless of its location (like earlier in `UINavigationBar` & `UITableViewHeader`). It is

[image: UISegmentControl-Tint Color]

However the TinitColor of `UInavigationBar` is still applicable on the `leftBarButtonItem` because there is no global tint scheme declared for the `UIBarButtonItem`, hence it is adopting the `tintColor` of the container it is added to.

***Adding more code to Clarify***

- Using global tint for `UISegmentedControl` & no other global tinting.

`[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:39.0/255.0 green:64.0/255.0 blue:112.0/255.0 alpha:1]];`

Result: You can see the segment control, but notice the backButton, which is having the default tint of `UINavigationBar`

[image: SegmentControl Tint Only]

- Using global tint for `UISegmentedControl` & `UINavigationBar`

`[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:39.0/255.0 green:64.0/255.0 blue:112.0/255.0 alpha:1]];`

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:39.0/255.0 green:64.0/255.0 blue:112.0/255.0 alpha:1]];`

Result: You can see the segment control tint & also notice the backButton, which is having the Global tint of `UINavigationBar`

[image: UISegmentedControl_ UINavigationBar_tintColor]

I have also done a default selection of `UISegmentedControl`. If you are getting any other result with this code then there must be some thing extra happening in your code.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but why would half of my set control be set to the global tint ? The whole thing should be set to the global tint. And why once I tap it, does it then change to the global tint.

Comment: Kindly refer the code added as an update to the answer. I guess you are having some thing extra in your code that is creating some conflicts. Please share your code then.

Comment: I'll check out my app asap, just so you know Im setting the global tint in the storyboard.

Comment: Sorry Smick, I am not well versed with StoryBoards. Any further code is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a big issue with tinting in Xcode 5.0.2 recently. I was playing with both *Global Tint* and *Tint* for various items when suddenly the inheritance of `tintColor` stopped working correctly. I ended up cleaning the Storyboard's `XML` file manually to fix things out.

If you're not doing any `UIAppearance` magic in your app, it sure looks like a bug to me.